# Dependency not available in project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to use the Cloudinary Scala API in my project. I've added it to the Build.scala as below

```
  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
 .settings(scoverageSettings:_*)
 .settings(
   version := appVersion,
   libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,    
   javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf",
   aggregate in Test := false,
   resolvers ++= Seq(
     "sonatype repo" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  )
 )
```

Where appDependencies contains

```
 Seq( //A few other unrelated dependencies here
   "com.cloudinary" %% "cloudinary-core-scala" % "0.9.6-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

When I import this project into IntelliJ

- All Cloudinary imports are flagged red
- IntelliJ is able to autocomplete my Cloudinary imports, but flags them as non project classes (ie. I can search for a cloudinary class and find them, but only when I select "search non project classes")
- When I run off the commandline (sbt compile), sbt is able to find the cloudinary classes and compile without an issue

This is making it very hard to code in my IDE as I don't get any syntax completion or highlighting.

I don't know where I'm going wrong with this. I've tried different Scala versions (I'm using 2.10, tried 2.11), different IntelliJ versions (14.1, 15), running an sbt clean, and recreating the project from scratch. Nothing has changed this so far.

Comment: IntelliJ can be a bit tricky with SBT sometimes, although latest versions seem to have improved *a lot*. Usually, when you change `Build.sbt`, Idea will notify you that project has changed so you can reload it, all dependencies should be downloaded automatically on reload and IDE should handle all of them properly from that point on...

Comment: Unfortunately, changing my build file (using build.scala file actually), does trigger a re-download, but results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, I tried the following
- Invalidating caches/restarting
- Switching version of the dependency from 0.9.6 to 0.9.7
- Cloning a new repo, recreating a new IntelliJ project

Each time the behaviour was the same. However, when I moved my code into a different package (Didn't matter what package I moved it to) - IntelliJ started picking up the class files. I don't have a solid theory as to what is/was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do force refresh of sbt project from IDEA's "SBT" toolbar.

Comment: Tried that... Didn't fix the problem.